# Navbar toggler de Boostrap invertida

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estaba probando una de las barras por defecto que se muestran en la página oficial de Bootstrap pero el nombre me queda invertido con respecto al botón toggler y aparte no se muestra del todo bien.

Así se ve (noten que está en pantalla maximizada e igual se ve el boton):

[image: asi se ve:]

Deberia ser asi:

[image: deberia ser asi:]

y cuando está maximizado:

[image: y cuando esta maximizado]

El codigo tiene un CSS propio pero no tiene modificacion alguna.
No sé si estoy vinculando mal alguno de los archivos o me falta agregar algo porque lo pruebo en cualquier página y funciona. Dejo el código:

```
<div class="text-primary container header">
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem</p>
</div>


<!-- Esta es la barra que estoy tratando de implementar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-
            toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-
            expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
          </span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

link de la barra: [Barra de Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

Comment: ¿Tiene CSS en su estilo propio ?  Sí es así ,  añadir a la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está cambiado respecto al de Bootstrap. Si añades elementos nuevos en determinados contextos no obtendrás el resultado deseado salvo que añadas más css.

A continuación tienes un ejemplo de cómo quedaría el código:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Título</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Título</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hola Pedro gracias por responder, tu codigo me sirvio pero no entiendo porque el mio esta mal, literalmente copie y pegue el codigo de la pagina de Bootstrap sin modificar nada (para que se entienda, el que esta debajo de la frase que dice _"And because we use classes for our navs, you can avoid the list-based approach entirely if you like."_ en esta pagina: [https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) sin embargo tu ejemplo difiere completamente del mio.

Comment: Estoy investigando al parecer tengo algun problema con la v4 porque si uso este codigo pero con el link de la version 4.0.0 se ve mal, incluso si el codigo que postee yo en primer lugar le cambio la version a la 3.3.7 anda bien. ¿Puede que sean inconmpatibles algunas de las clases con la nueva version?.

Comment: Este código se corresponde con la versión 3.3